# add AxWEBBrowser in my toolbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How can I add AxWEBBrowser in my toolbox?
I tried to customized my toolbox by 
TOOLS -> Customized toolbox -> Com components - >
but i didnt found any AxWEBBrowser.
I also include in my reference the AxInterop.SHDocVw and Interop.SHDocVw.
What else i need to do to add AxWEBBrowser?
Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You will need to select "Microsoft Web Browser" from COM Components.

Incase you need to browse, the file name is "ieframe.dll". It should normally be in System32 folder.